# switch between SetStateDynamicEntity Update and Create

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

The PipeLine Stage is Pre-Valadation:

Does anyone know how to switch between EntityReference and  Entity. 
I have got a problem. I have to fire  a Plugin by SetStateDynamicEntity ,Update and Create
If I fire the SetStateDynamicEntity it doesn’t like (Entity target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];) because it doesn’t have a target , it have got a enitymonika and it’s not entity 
But if I fire Update and create it stop over there it want a target
How can switch between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your plugin is triggered with SetStateDynamicEntity message you should register preImage to get fields - http://inogic.com/blog/2010/07/pre-image-post-image-explained/

Comment: The only problem is : it doesnt have got a preimage ; because it driggering the update and create by Pre_valadation

Comment: In any of PreValidation or PreOperation of Update or SetState message - Pre Image is available so that is not a problem.